# Aireplay handshakes, were working now has an error

Tags: aircrack-ng, wifite

I'm trying to learn to do pen testing and wifi cracking.

I had captured handshakes and begun cracking the handshake a day ago, with the password not being in my dictionary list.

When trying with a new list I received this error.

```
Invalid packet capture length 1859175202 - corrupted file?
```

Now whenever I capture the handshake it is coming up with this error.

I have now begun using wifite2 to try and get around this issue. It is not capturing handshakes or deauthing the test wifi point whatsoever - this is relatively simple to do for me when using just airplay / aircrack.

I'm thinking - should I delete the saved handshakes? And where are they held? I had put them in pkg file based on the tutorial on https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=newbie_guide

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Load the captured packets into Wireshark, and check if they are valid. If you find some .pcap file corrupted, you can safely delete it. If you already have a valid handshake, you don't need to capture again for testing against another dictionary list, for the same target.
Having a lot of handshakes won't help to speed up the cracking. You need only *one* valid handshake for each target (which is composed of a minimum of two packets), but you must be sure that the handshake is valid, otherwise you may waste your time. Take a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184554/what-are-the-factors-making-a-wpa2-handshake-suitable-for-cracking) for more details.